# Вход на/в фуд-корт

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вход на/в фуд-корт?

Answer (score 1):

Если это обширная площадка типа теннисного корта (пусть даже закрытого), на которой организовано питание (ресторанный дворик) или просто торговля съестным, то поступать надо так же, как с "кортом" (предлог **на** - на площадке, на неё заходят посетители). Если вдруг так назван обычный продуктовый магазин (супермаркет) в закрытом помещении, то предлог **в**, поскольку по расшифровывке самого слова затруднительно определить *тип помещения* - он всё и решает.

Comment: Это и есть ресторанный дворик, по Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ресторанный_дворик